# sort tags by tag ID in Wordpress admin panel

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting

I want to sort tags list by tag id in my WordPress admin panel. There is 1000s tag in admin tag list and I want to know which are the latest added tags, but there are options to sort with Name, Description, Slug, and Coun but no option to sort by oldest or newest. Please tell me how can i add one more column "sort by ID".

Answer (score 0):

Add this to functions.php

```
add_filter('manage_edit-post_tag_columns','post_tag_columns_func');
function post_tag_columns_func($columns){
    $columns[ 'id' ]='ID';
    return $columns;
}
add_filter('manage_edit-post_tag_sortable_columns','post_tag_sortable_columns_func');
function post_tag_sortable_columns_func($columns){
    $columns['id']='ID';
    return $columns;
}
add_filter('manage_post_tag_custom_column','add_post_tag_column_content',10,3);
function add_post_tag_column_content($content,$column,$id){
    return $id;
}
```